# $_Session['user'] not being recognised PHP

Tags: php, session

I would like a different message to appear depending on whether the user logged in is admin or not. I have two **$_SESSION** variables in my `session.php` that take me either to a member's page or an admin page depending on the username/password combination. That works fine, however when I am trying to display a different message for each session, only the first message is displayed, and I have tried heaps of variations of this code and searched online but I can't find an answer. Help!

```
<?php

include 'session.php';
include 'Header.php';

?>
<div id="main">
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['login_admin'])){

 echo "HELLO admin";


}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
     echo "Hello";
 }



?>
</div>
```

So my webpage is recognising 'login_admin' but when i login as 'login_user' it displays the admin message, not the user message.

EDIT: session_start() is in all of my pages.

Login Code:

```
<body>
<?php
include 'Header.php';
?>
<div id="main">
<div id="login">
<center>
<h2>Login</h2><br />
<form action = "session.php" method = "post" name="log">
              <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name =   "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
              <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
              <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
           </form>
</center>
</div>
<br />
</div>
<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
</body>
```

Session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "movies");




  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // username and password sent from form 

  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']); 

  $sql = "SELECT ID FROM login WHERE username = '$myusername' and password =  '$mypassword'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

  if($count == 1) {

     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
     $_SESSION['login_admin'] = $myusername;


     header("location: MembersPage.php");

  }

 if($_SESSION['login_admin'] == 'admin'){


     $_SESSION['login_admin'] = $myusername;

      header("location: admin.php");

 }


  else {
     echo  "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }




  }

 ?>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(session_destroy()) {
  header("Location: Login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you remember to start the session `session_start();`? And can both `login_admin` and `login_user` be set at the same time? Because PHP will only evaluate the first if-block if it returns true (and ignore the rest), because they are in the same structure.

Comment: Do you unset `$_SESSION['login_admin']`when you set `$_SESSION['login_user']`and vice versa?

Comment: you missed `session_start()`;

Comment: I have include "session.php" on all my pages, would i need session_start() on them as well? 

I destroy the session when I log out, so when I login either as user or admin I still get the same message

Comment: @Qirel So if I want both statements to work depending on which $_Session is active, how would I go about it? Eventually I want to have messages/links/html etc. that are displayed depending on whether a user or admin is logged in.

Comment: The question is if both sessions can be active at one time? Or can only one of them be active? And can you show how you set these sessions (when logging in) and destroy these sessions (when logging out)?

Comment: If $_Session['login_user'] is active, a message will display on one of the webpages, but if $_Session['login_admin'] is active, a different message will display. They won't be active at the same time.

Sorry if i'm not good at explaining, I fairly new to php and this is for a school project so it's pretty basic.

Comment: So, based on your edit of codes, I can easily spot the mistake. Whenever someone logs in, you set both sessions. So both sessions are always set. You need to restructure your login-code in such a way that `$_SESSION['login_admin']` is ONLY set when an admin is logged in.

Comment: As an added notice: You should always use `exit;` after calling `header("Location: ..")`. And you really should take advantage of using prepared statements, as your code currently is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: So I edit my session.php? How would I go about making sure $_SESSION['login_admin'] is only set when admin is logged in?

Comment: This will never be uploaded, its just staying on localhost atm, but thank you for helping me so far

Comment: The best thing would be to have a field in the database indicating if it's an admin or not (so you can have multiple admins, regardless of username), but the way I understand your current structure, it would be something like `if ($count == 1) { if ($myusername == "admin") { $_SESSION['admin_login'] = $myusername; header("Location: toAdminArea.html"); exit; } else { $_SESSION['login_user] = $myusername; header("Location: toMemberArea.html"); exit; } } else { /* Invalid login */ }`

Comment: Ok I will try editing that part of my code with your suggestion

Comment: Just noticed I used the wrong indexes compared to your code, I used `admin_login` instead of `login_admin` and can't edit the comment now - just a heads up if you try that sample-code.

Comment: Like I said though, there are better approaches to handling separating of admins and users, like storing a "rank" value in the users-table and check for that instead - but if this works for you, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to use `session_start();`. Add this at the top of page.

I would suggest if you are checking `session` in each or most pages then add `session_start` on `header.php` (if you created). this will save you from such problmes

This is the problem

```
if($count == 1) {

     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
     $_SESSION['login_admin'] = $myusername;   

     header("location: MembersPage.php");

  }
```

you are setting `login_admin`,`login_user` every time either user login or admin so this `$_SESSION['login_admin']` always has value show you are getting always welcome admin

Create a field in your `table` name `user_role` and place value for `admin` and `user` like

```
1 for admin
2 for user
```

at the time of login check this field value and if it is 1 then set only `login_admin` and if it is 2 then set only `login_user`  like

```
 $sql = "SELECT ID,user_role FROM login WHERE username = '$myusername' and password =  '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);   

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count == 1) {
    if($row['user_role'] == 1){
      $_SESSION['login_admin'] = 'admin'; 
      header("location: admin.php");       
      }
      else{
      $_SESSION['login_user'] = 'user';
      header("location: MembersPage.php");
      }
 }
```

Comment: Ok I got rid of $_SESSION['login_admin'] from that part of the code, and now instead of getting the message for an admin in both sessions, I get the message for the user in both sessions haha. So instead of always getting 'Hello admin' I now get 'Hello' when I log in as either admin or user. But at least something changed so I think i'm on the right track..

Comment: This is not  proper way try my answer create user_role field in your table and then set that session only which is needed rest is your wish:)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) Method which is required if you want to Start a New Session or If you want to resume existing session.